# Get list of subdirectories which contain a file whose name contains a string

Tags: command-line, find

How can I get a list of the subdirectories which contain a file whose name matches a particular pattern?

More specifically, I am looking for directories which contain a file with the letter 'f' somewhere occurring in the file name.

Ideally, the list would not have duplicates and only contain the path without the filename.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq
```

The above finds all files below the current directory (`.`) that are regular files (`-type f`) and have `f` somewhere in their name (`-name '*f*'`).  Next, `sed` removes the file name, leaving just the directory name.  Then, the list of directories is sorted (`sort`) and duplicates removed (`uniq`).

The `sed` command consists of a single substitute.  It looks for matches to the regular expression `/[^/]+$` and replaces anything matching that with nothing.  The dollar sign means the end of the line.  `[^/]+'` means one or more characters that are not slashes.  Thus, `/[^/]+$` means all characters from the final slash to the end of the line.  In other words, this matches the file name at the end of the full path.  Thus, the sed command removes the file name, leaving unchanged the name of directory that the file was in.

#### Simplifications

Many modern `sort` commands support a `-u` flag which makes `uniq` unnecessary.   For GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort -u
```

And, for MacOS sed:

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' | sed -E 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort -u
```

Also, if your `find` command supports it, it is possible to have `find` print the directory names directly.  This avoids the need for `sed`:

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

#### More robust version (Requires GNU tools)

The above versions will be confused by file names that include newlines.  A more robust solution is to do the sorting on NUL-terminated strings:

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu | sed -z 's/$/\n/'
```

#### Simplified using dirname

Imagine needing the command in a script where command will be in single quotes, escaping sed command is painful and less than ideal, so replace with dirname.

Issues regard special chars and newline are also mute if you did not need to sort or directories names are not affected.

```
find . -type f -name "*f*" -exec dirname "{}" \; |sort -u
```

take care of newline issue:

```
find . -type f -name "*f*" -exec dirname -z "{}" \; |sort -zu |sed -z 's/$/\n/'
```

Comment: I have a lot of files that makes sorting them all too costly.  Throwing `uniq` into the mix helps a lot by removing the repeated lines that are already right next to each other.  `find . -type f -name '*f*' -printf '%h\0' | uniq -z | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'`.  Or if your tools are a little older, then uniq may not have the -z option. `find . -type f -name '*f*' -printf '%h\n' | uniq | sort -u`

Comment: MacOS Users: The sed flag is not -r. For some reason its -E

Comment: @David Very true.  Answer updated to show `-E` for MacOS.

Comment: RE: `file names that include newlines` - bonus points for diligence and taking extra care; don't think I have ever encountered those, though - in what context would those ever occur ? you aren't talking about whitespace as in spaces or tabs, are you ?

Comment: @ssc newlines in file names are rare.  Good programmers, however, don't want to write code that works merely _most_ of the time.  The goal is to have code that works _all_ of the time.

Answer (score 43):

Why not try this:

```
find / -name '*f*' -printf "%h\n" | sort -u
```

Comment: Best answer. Entirely POSIX-compatible, unlike some answers above, above, and also earns the special *The Shortest Pipeline* prize :).

Comment: I would love to see someone show the timing of this vs the others above, because I get the feeling this is by far the fastest.

Comment: @kkm I agree this is the best solution but [POSIX specs for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) are actually quite sparse—the `-printf` operator is *not* specified.  This doesn't work with BSD `find`.  So, *not* "entirely POSIX compatible."  (Though `sort -u` [is in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).)

Comment: what is mac equivalent for this? `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Wouldn't `uniq` be enough? The same directory would always be traversed in sequence by `find`, or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 8):

There are essentially 2 methods you can use to do this. One will parse the string while the other will operate on each file. Parsing the string use a tool such as `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` is obviously going to be faster but here's an example showing both, as well as how you can "profile" the 2 methods.

#### Sample data

For the examples below we'll use the following data

```
$ touch dir{1..3}/dir{100..112}/file{1..5}
$ touch dir{1..3}/dir{100..112}/nile{1..5}
$ touch dir{1..3}/dir{100..112}/knife{1..5}
```

Delete some of the `*f*` files from `dir1/*`:

```
$ rm dir1/dir10{0..2}/*f*
```

#### Approach #1 - Parsing via strings

Here we're going to use the following tools, `find`, `grep`, and `sort`.

```
$ find . -type f -name '*f*' | grep -o "\(.*\)/" | sort -u | head -5
./dir1/dir103/
./dir1/dir104/
./dir1/dir105/
./dir1/dir106/
./dir1/dir107/
```

#### Approach #2 - Parsing using files

Same tool chain as before, except this time we'll be using `dirname` instead of `grep`.

```
$ find . -type f -name '*f*' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u | head -5
./dir1/dir103
./dir1/dir104
./dir1/dir105
./dir1/dir106
./dir1/dir107
```

**NOTE:** The above examples are using `head -5` to merely limit the amount of output we're dealing with for these examples. They'd normally be removed to get your full listing!

#### Comparing the results

We can use `time` to take a look at the 2 approaches.

*dirname*

```
real        0m0.372s
user        0m0.028s
sys         0m0.106s
```

*grep*

```
real        0m0.012s
user        0m0.009s
sys         0m0.007s
```

So it's always best to deal with the strings if possible.

#### Alternative string parsing methods

*grep & PCRE*

```
$ find . -type f -name '*f*' | grep  -oP '^.*(?=/)' | sort -u
```

*sed*

```
$ find . -type f -name '*f*' | sed 's#/[^/]*$##' | sort -u
```

*awk*

```
$ find . -type f -name '*f*' | awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Comment: @Muhd - yes the calls to dirname are slow. I'm working on an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one I find useful:

```
find . -type f -name "*somefile*" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-exec` switch to run dirname and get the directory name instead of the file name. This has the added benefit of being POSIX compatible.

```
find . -name "*file*" -exec dirname {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is shamelessly based on slm answer. It was an interesting approach, but it has a limitation if the file and/or directory names had special chars (space, semi-column...). A good habit is to use `find /somewhere -print0 | xargs -0 someprogam`.

### Sample data

For the examples below we'll use the following data

```
mkdir -p dir{1..3}/dir\ {100..112}
touch dir{1..3}/dir\ {100..112}/nile{1..5}
touch dir{1..3}/dir\ {100..112}/file{1..5}
touch dir{1..3}/dir\ {100..112}/kni\ fe{1..5}
```

Delete some of the `*f*` files from `dir1/*/`:

```
rm dir1/dir\ 10{0..2}/*f*
```

### Approach #1 - Parsing using files

```
$ find -type f -name '*f*' -print0 | sed -e 's#/[^/]*\x00#\x00#g' | sort -zu | xargs -0 -n1 echo | head -n5
./dir1/dir 103
./dir1/dir 104
./dir1/dir 105
./dir1/dir 106
./dir1/dir 107
```

**NOTE**: The above examples are using `head -5` to merely limit the amount of output we're dealing with for these examples. They'd normally be removed to get your full listing! also, replace the `echo`which whatever command you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -aU dirs # array with unique values
dirs=( **/*f*(ND:h) )

printf -rC1 -- $dirs
```

That makes no assumption as to what characters or non-characters file names otherwise contain.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this variation that doesn't use `sort` or `unique` usefull

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.log' -print -quit
```

The advantage is that you don't have to wait for the whole tree to be traversed before sorted.

1. Find all directories `find . -type d -print0`
2. For each directory `| xargs -0 -I{}`, find a file in the current directory `-maxdepth 1` that matches the pattern `-iname '*.log'` (case insensitive). If found, print the filename `-print` and stop traversing that directory `quit`

Alternatively

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I// find // -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.log' -exec dirname {} \; -quit
```

which just prints the parent directories name, as inspired by [Snowbuilders answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637462/355088).

Comment: Nice idea, but sadly slower. I compared `time find "$src_path" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -path "$src_path/4???_?/archive" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%h\n" -quit` (1.5s) with `time find "$src_path" -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -path "$src_path/4???_?/archive/*" -printf "%h\0" | sort -zu` (0.5s). In my case I have ~1000 dirs without any files and ~20 dirs with files.

Comment: @mgutt why the different _depth_ options?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this solution is slower. One of the main reasons for this approach was not waiting for the entire tree traversal, required by sort. I would probably opt for one of the top rated answers if I was trying to do this today, but probably just `find / -name '*f*' -printf "%h\n" | uniq`. Sorting shouldn't be necessary

Comment: The different depths are (hopefully) performance tweaks to avoid traversal into unnecessary (sub)directories. For example "depth 2" targets directly the parent directory of the files without going deeper. Regarding `uniq`: yes should work as find does not return the files in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have more than one file matching per directory (otherwise you will have duplicates), in bash you can leverage from the `for` construct and on variable expansion (as in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658717/2436175), in this case we remove from the path everything after the last `/`)

```
for i in `find -name \*<your_filename_string>\*`; do echo ${i%/*}; done
```