# find directories not containing a file

Tags: find

How can I use the `find` command to locate directories that do NOT contain a particular file? E.g., if I have bunch of directories that should be under revision control, can I search and find the ones that do not have a `.git` sub-directory? Or, my project specifies that all modules should have a `utilities.py` file; how do I search to find which sub-directories do not yet have the required file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/196966) that might work for your case is,

```
find . -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/utilities.py" ';' -print
```

**Testing**

1. I created 4 sub directories named **dir1**, **dir2**, **dir3** and
   **dir with spaces**. I wanted to test if this handles spaces equally well which is why I created a directory with spaces in its name.
2. I created files *file1*, *file2*, *file3* and *file4* in **dir2**
   and **dir3**.
3. In **dir1**, I created *file1*, *file2*, *file3*.
4. In **dir with spaces**, I created a file named *file with spaces*.
5. Now, I execute my find command as,

   ```
   find . -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/file with spaces" ';' -print
   ```
6. The output I get is,

   ```
   .
   ./dir1
   ./dir2
   ./dir3
   ```
7. As expected, since the directory **dir with spaces** contains the
   file named *file with spaces* it is not listed in the output. If I
   change the `find` command to have *file4* in it, the output I get
   is,

   ```
   .
   ./dir with spaces
   ./dir1
   ```

**EDIT**

However, the above approach doesn't seem to work if we have nested subdirectories and the file in the final level. So to overcome such scenarios, you could modify your find to something like discussed over [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111952/47538).

```
find . -type f -not -name 'utilities.py' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u
```

As Gilles suggests in his [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158238/find-directories-not-containing-a-file/158240#comment259277_158240),

> For `.git`, it would be more useful to skip directories that have a
>   parent containing `.git`. You can do this by adding a -prune in the
>   right place:
>
> ```
> find . -type d -exec test -e "{}/.git" ';' -prune -o -print
> ```

Comment: This will list all files and directories except utilities.py, without telling me which DIRECTORIES do NOT have that file in them.

Comment: @ChrisDR, please see the updates.

Comment: +1 but I'd delete the first suggestion since it does not help the OP.

Comment: @terdon, thanks. I deleted it. But it seems the latest edit is something what the OP might be interested in since it deals with the subdirectories as well.

Comment: For `.git`, it would be more useful to skip directories that have a parent containing `.git`. You can do this by adding a `-prune` in the right place: `find . -type d -exec test -e "{}/.git" ';' -prune -o -print`

Comment: @Gnouc, I got it from another source which I have referenced. So, I am not sure about it.

Comment: If you feel it is not needed, I will go ahead and remove it after I test it once I get back home. :)