# Obtain filepath of directories containing a particular filetype in alphabetical/numerical order

Tags: find, filenames, path

I have a directory that contains 800 subdirectories named `disp-001 ... disp-800`. All these sub-directories need to contain a specific file say `stdout`.
One among them does not contain the file and I need to find the folder that does not have the file.
If I try

```
find . -name "stdout"
```

it returns me the values of all files, but they are not ordered from 001 to 800, which makes it very difficult for me to identify the folder. Is there a way to order the output such that they are ordered numerically?

**NOTE:**

I'm leaving this question unedited to demonstrate  (atleast to myself) a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). All I needed was to identify directories not containing a particular file, but instead this question was about a particular attempted solution to the problem. The solution for finding a directory that does not contain a particular file is provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158240/77596).

Comment: Is your question about finding the directory that does *not* have a given file, or about sorting the output of find?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' dir*/stdout`

Comment: See also `zsh`'s `printf '%s\n' dir*(/^e:'[ -e $REPLY/stdout ]':)`

Comment: Sorry its a XY problem. I need the directory that does not contain the file. I will rephrase the question

Comment: +1 to Stephane's zsh answer for the trailing (functional!) :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use the shell for that instead:

```
$ for dir in disp-{001..800}; do [ -f "$dir"/stdout ] || echo "$dir"; done
disp-389
```

In my test, `disp-389` was the only directory lacking that file and so the only one printed.

If your shell doesn't support that form of brace expansion, just use `for dir in disp*` or, assuming you want to check all directories, `for dir in */`.

Comment: That assumes `zsh` or a recent version of `bash` (4.0 or above).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair enough, edited to add a more portable way.