# How can I use the find command to list all the file types in a directory and all subdirectories?

Tags: shell, files, find

How can I use the find command to recursively list all the file extensions in a directory?  Using wildcards I can find all the files of a certain type:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3'
```

but what I want to to list to search a directory and all sub directories and list all of the file extensions found.

Comment: Duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111949/98965

Comment: @GAD3R, @Mongrel I think this not what the OP wanted. From how I understand the question he wants to use `find` to get a list of all extension (not files) that are found, e.g. `find [find magic]` -> `.c, .h, .cpp`, see this solution below http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331389/64248. So I vote to leave this question open.

Comment: @countermode - it's a dupe of another Q - see the link in my comment above

Comment: Not sure why it matters if it was a duplicate post as I answered my own question before anyone suggested it was a duplicate... I say close the question... I tried to delete it myself, but could not.

Answer (score 6):

A little more searching revealed this solution:

```
find . -type f | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}' | sort| uniq -c | sort -g
```

Not sure why **[this link](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7878/list-all-file-extensions-in-a-directory)** did not show up in previous searches.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more robust than your solution:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

That is, since you're looking for the part of a filename following a dot, it's important to add that detail to filters of `find`. Otherwise files without an extension will give strange results: the entire path may be printed, or if the path contained a dot in one of the intermediary subdirectories, then a partial path after the last dot will be printed.